Gradient Descent for Multiple Linear Regression
I was reviewing the gradient descent (GD) for multiple linear regression and noticed that the partial derivatives or gradients for each weight (w_j) only differ by its corresponding feature value (x_ij).

Now, I always try to make some intuitive sense of why some things are the way they are, and I often try to make physical sense due to my physics background. Still, for this one, I can't seem to think of anything other than understanding it as a direct consequence of taking PD of linear combination.
Does anyone have any other intuitive sense to make out of this algorithm?

Not a programming question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info for more.
